# Difference between physical and programmatically click on ListView

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I am clicking `ListView` item programmatically on `onCreate` method like below:

```
    // setting listener for ListView item click
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                changeView(i);
            }
        });

    // Clicking ListView first position programmatically.
    listview.performItemClick(listview.getChildAt(0), 0,
                listview.getAdapter().getItemId(0));
```

In above code when i debug the code `changeView(i);` is calling properly for both **programmatic** and **physical** click.

I am using `changeView()` to change colour of ListView item views (`TextView` and `ImageView`) like below:

```
private void changeView(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = getViewByPosition(i, listview);
            ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            if (i == position) {
                imgIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.app_red));
                txtTitle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.app_red));
            } else {
                imgIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.colorWhite));
                txtTitle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.colorWhite));
            }
        }

        lvSlideMenu.setItemChecked(position, true);
        lvSlideMenu.setSelection(position);
    }
```

Where `getViewByPosition()` method is used to get view of ListView item:

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {
            return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
        } else {
            final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
            return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM :** Above code is changing colour of `TextView` and `ImageView` of list item when i click **physically** (by hand) but not **programmatically**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending view in chnageView()

```
  changeView(view);
```

And in chnageView()

```
ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
```

Comment: v is view passed in changeview(view) method. remove for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = getViewByPosition(i, listview);

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the code, I can deduce that, when you are changing color programmatically and changeView() is called, your color change code part is not executed :

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = getViewByPosition(i, listview);
            ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            if (i == position) {
                imgIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.app_red));
                txtTitle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.app_red));
            } else {
                imgIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.colorWhite));
                txtTitle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.colorWhite));
            }
        }
```

Can you please check if for block is executed.

Comment: i set setOnItemClickListener before programmatically click on item and this is calling colour changing code. I debug to see if the code is called or not and its calling.